# Linq Dynamic GroupBY with generic table T

Tags: c#, linq

Is it at all possible to do a GroupBy using a dynamic field name on a generic set table ? I've done some research but nothing is making sense and here's what I am basically trying.

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T : class
{
   public List<String> ListBranches()
   {
       return context.Set<T>()
                     .GroupBy( x => "Branch" )
                     .Select( "Branch" )
                     .ToList();
   }
}
```

I need to group the field Branch as there can be at least 2 branches with the same name. So I have to group them...and "Branch" is a column name in the table T...But there's many tables in the database that have a column called Branch..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This looks more like dynamic `Select` followed by `Distinct`

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, do you perhaps have an example of how I can achieve that? Sorry I am fairly new to linq...

Comment: return context.Set<T>().Distinct(x => x.Branch).ToList();

Comment: Grab the `QueryableExtensions` class from this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0P6St). Then use `return context.Set<T>().SelectString("Branch").Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: @IvanStoev, this seems to have worked exactly the way I would like it to... Thanks a lot for your help. Maybe you should post your solution as an answer so it can help someone else who might stumble on the same request...

Comment: I can't because the question is closed as duplicate. But that's not essential, glad that helped solving your issue. Cheers.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a mil! Also thanks for whoever that marked it as duplicate...